# How to add an animation into infragistics grid row

Tags: user-interface, infragistics, user-experience, ultrawingrid

I am developing UI form that has infragistics grid. Users  can delete, submit some records in the grid. Because of long running task (deleting, insertion...) some grid records have to display the static or dynamic progress. To improve UX I think to add a virtual column that can display animated gif or just draw a fixed or animated text. How can I implement this functionality with that grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to look at the samples installed with your NetAdvantage controls.
In particular the samples on:

- Alpha blending (display a background image with various level of opacity)
- Flood fill (Use a cell or column as progress bar)
- Special effects (Pulsing or blinking a cell)

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I have found it.